# Converting from 2D lat/lon matrix into 1D lat/lon array

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I am working with a NetCDF file, that has no coordinates. My lat/lon values are sorted in the variables in a form of a matrix, in a way lat (x,y) and lon(x,y). My goal here is to extract a lat and a lon 1D array to assign it as coordinates, as these must be a 1D array.

Here is how the dataset originally looks like:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:             (y: 10980, x: 10980)
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Data variables: (12/20)
    lon                 (y, x) float32 ...
    lat                 (y, x) float32 ...
```

For example, the lat variable looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'lat' (y: 10980, x: 10980)>
array([[41.52681 , 41.52681 , 41.526814, ..., 41.54671 , 41.54671 , 41.546715],
       [41.52672 , 41.526722, 41.526722, ..., 41.54662 , 41.546623, 41.546623],
       [41.52663 , 41.52663 , 41.526634, ..., 41.54653 , 41.54653 , 41.54653 ],
       ...,
       [40.538834, 40.538837, 40.538837, ..., 40.55806 , 40.55806 , 40.558064],
       [40.538746, 40.538746, 40.53875 , ..., 40.55797 , 40.557972, 40.557972],
       [40.538654, 40.53866 , 40.53866 , ..., 40.55788 , 40.55788 , 40.55788 ]],
      dtype=float32)
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Attributes:
    parameter:      lat
    standard_name:  latitude
    long_name:      latitude
    units:          degree_north
```

So in order to convert both variables into 1D array, I do the following:

```
#First I open the dataset
file_to_input = 'landsat.nc'
nc1 = xr.open_dataset(file_to_input)

#Then I take the y axis from lat:
lati = nc1.lat[:,0]
#And the x axis from lon:
long = nc1.lon[0,:]

#To then assign them as 1D array to the dataset:
nc1 = nc1.assign_coords({'x':long,'y':lati})
nc1 = nc1.rio.set_spatial_dims('x', 'y')

#I set the proper CRS for the varaible to export (EPSG: 32631):
nc1var = nc1['ndci'].rio.set_crs("epsg:32631")

#And then I export it as a geotiff:
nc1var.rio.to_raster('ndci.tiff')
```

I am working with a NetCDF file, that has no coordinates. My lat/lon values are sorted in the variables in a form of a matrix, in a way lat (x,y) and lon(x,y). My goal here is to extract a lat and a lon 1D array to assign it as coordinates, as these must be a 1D array.

Here is how the dataset originally looks like:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:             (y: 10980, x: 10980)
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Data variables: (12/20)
    lon                 (y, x) float32 ...
    lat                 (y, x) float32 ...
```

For example, the lat variable looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'lat' (y: 10980, x: 10980)>
array([[41.52681 , 41.52681 , 41.526814, ..., 41.54671 , 41.54671 , 41.546715],
       [41.52672 , 41.526722, 41.526722, ..., 41.54662 , 41.546623, 41.546623],
       [41.52663 , 41.52663 , 41.526634, ..., 41.54653 , 41.54653 , 41.54653 ],
       ...,
       [40.538834, 40.538837, 40.538837, ..., 40.55806 , 40.55806 , 40.558064],
       [40.538746, 40.538746, 40.53875 , ..., 40.55797 , 40.557972, 40.557972],
       [40.538654, 40.53866 , 40.53866 , ..., 40.55788 , 40.55788 , 40.55788 ]],
      dtype=float32)
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Attributes:
    parameter:      lat
    standard_name:  latitude
    long_name:      latitude
    units:          degree_north
```

So in order to convert both variables into 1D array, I do the following:

```
#First I open the dataset
file_to_input = 'landsat.nc'
nc1 = xr.open_dataset(file_to_input)

#Then I take the y axis from lat:
lati = nc1.lat[:,0]
#And the x axis from lon:
long = nc1.lon[0,:]

#To then assign them as 1D array to the dataset:
nc1 = nc1.assign_coords({'x':long,'y':lati})
nc1 = nc1.rio.set_spatial_dims('x', 'y')

#I set the proper CRS for the varaible to export (EPSG: 32631):
nc1var = nc1['ndci'].rio.set_crs("epsg:32631")

#And then I export it as a geotiff:
nc1var.rio.to_raster('ndci.tiff')
```

So far so good. The problem comes when I visualize the exported geotiff, the GeoTIFF is SLIGHTLY shifted. In the image below you can see a small shift down of the GeoTIFF with respect to the basemap. I tried using this method with other good working TIFFs and the same shift happens, so I assume it has to do with the way I am changing from 2D lat lon to 1D array.

[image: tiff extracted and not located properly]

I think it can be achieved with pyproj transformer or something like that, but I have no idea how to use that with lat/lon 2D grid into 1D.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. I do not think you can save a dataset as a raster with varying cell resolutions. You would need to do your analysis in python.
I am commenting to add importance to this post.